# How to set maximum levels for treeItems in a tree (SWT)?

Tags: swt

I have an Tree and a button to add treeItems in each treeItem, sow how can I prevent user to make more then 2 level of treeItems on a tree in SWT?

Comment: Have you tried anythings ? this is not a coding service. Try somethings, if it does not works, we will help you. please refer to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for more information

Comment: I haven't worked so far with such structures and I didn't find the answer on the internet, I thought there was a direct function to do it. It is very strange that it doesn't exist, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
private int getLevelOfItem(TreeItem item)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        while(item.getParentItem() != null)
        {
            item = item.getParentItem();
            counter++;
        }

        return counter;
    }
```